# Windows 10 Skype call

Tags: windows-10, skype

I am using Windows 10 and Skype.
Skype has a new feature for Live Captions of a Video Call.
This is great, since I am deaf, it allows me to communicate with friends and family.

I have been a software developer for 30+ years.

When Skype gets an incoming call it shows a notification on screen and I guess sounds an audio ringtone.
This is useless for the deaf. Unless I am in front of the computer, I'll miss the notification, and the ringtone falls upon deaf ears.

What I would like to do is flash an alerter bulb when Skype receives an incoming call. I would need to have a program "listen" for the notification or ringtone. Flashing the bulb is easy - I have that.

I have thought of a Windows notification listener or Windows message hook, neither has panned out.

Maybe I am reinventing the wheel. Maybe Windows 10 or Skype already has this?

Can anyone think of a way to do this or point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Barry.

Comment: Just a heads up, this is more of a stack overflow question as it is worded right now.  Have you seen the [Skype for developers](https://dev.skype.com/) page?  I have not developed anything for Skype; however, MS has pretty thorough documentation for everything which I have ever seen with their name on it.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I try to post on StackOverflow, but a page pops up and ultimately directs me here or some different related site. I agree this is really a StackOverflow type question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put skype on your phone, so that you can get vibration notifications just like you would with a phone call?  You can still connect on your PC if you know a call is coming in from the phone

Comment: Check this out too if you like to play with hardware :-) https://www.resdevops.com/2016/11/07/building-a-skypelync-notification-light/